Property of triple systems
A triple system is a subspace $T\subseteq B(H)$ for a Hilbert space $H$ such that $xy^* z\in T$ for all $x,y,z \in T$.
Consider the $C^*$-algebra $B$ which consists of the closed linear span of the elements $xy^*$ with $x,y\in T$. Is it true that $BT = T$? Clearly the inclusion $BT\subseteq T$ holds, by definition of triple system. For the converse, I tried to argue using Cohen's factorisation theorem, but couldn't finish.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Yes. Let $u_\lambda$ be an approximate identity for $B$. Let $x \in T$. Then as $xx^\ast \in B$, we have,
$$\|u_\lambda x - x\|^2 = \|(u_\lambda - 1)xx^\ast (u_\lambda - 1)\| \leq \|(u_\lambda - 1)xx^\ast\| = \|u_\lambda xx^\ast - xx^\ast\| \to 0$$
So the result follows by Cohen’s factorization theorem.
